# ODBC connection to external data

Tags: odbc, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there any way to get an ODBC-Connection to an ( external ) table from AX2012R2, **without** using a DSN in the ODBC-connections?

It worked fine in 2009 with something like

systemInfo = SysSQLSystemInfo::construct();

```
loginProperty = new LoginProperty();

loginProperty.setServer(systemInfo.getLoginServer());
loginProperty.setDatabase(systemInfo.getloginDatabase());

conString = strFmt( 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};'
                    + 'Server=%1;'
                    + 'Database=%2;'
                    , systemInfo.getLoginServer()
                    , systemInfo.getloginDatabase()
                    );

if ( <someFunctionToCheckForTrusedConnectin> )
{
   conString += '"Trusted_Connection=Yes;"';
}
else
{
    conString += strFmt( '"id=%1;'
                        + 'pwd=%2;"'
                        , _userName
                        , _passWord
                        );
}

loginProperty.setOther( conString );

try
{
    odbc = new OdbcConnection( loginProperty);
}
catch
{
    throw error(#DatabaseConnectionError);
}
```

But it throws errors in 2012:

```
Objekt 'OdbcConnection' konnte nicht erstellt werden.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben
```

I've googled for hours ( maybe days.. ) and didn't find any working example yet.

**Edit:**

If I modify the following two lines of code

```
loginProperty.setServer(systemInfo.getLoginServer());
loginProperty.setDatabase(systemInfo.getloginDatabase());
```

and enter server / database **as plain text**, it seems to work on first look, **BUT** it doesn't matter, if I enter an invalid username and/or password.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a system or user DSN?

This will establish a driver for the connection. You do not need to specify server or database.

Comment: Because of roll-outs. It's less effort "just" to have the model insted of having to create a DSN also.

Comment: You can reduce the pain by using ODBC server side only.

Comment: Yes, maybe it "reduces the pain", but you **have** to create an ODBC-connection. At least on the server.

Answer (score 0):

All our interfaces use this and it works, we store our connection parameters, ie database name and database server name in a table, **note the DSN is commented out, so is not necessary**:

```
loginProperty = new LoginProperty();
loginProperty.setServer(ImportJournalParameters.ExternalServerName);
// loginProperty.setDSN("ServerSQL10");
loginProperty.setDatabase(ImportJournalParameters.ExternalDBName);
connection = new OdbcConnection(loginProperty);
info('Login Process Successful - connection established');
```