# ConnectionString is incorrect in axapta

Tags: axapta, x++, ax

I want to connect to the other database using `LoginProperty` class. I did it in two different ways:

1. Create a DNS system object, using loginProperty class and connect to the DB. This way it works fine.
2. In the other way, i wants to creat a 'Connection String' and connect to the DB. In this way i am getting an error.

> ODBC operation failed. Unable to logon to the database.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and there is no standard driver.

My Connection string is:

```
connectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}; Server=MSS2008-term\\\\SQLServer; Database=db; user ID=sa; Password=ABC.123";
loginProperty.setOther(connectionString); 
conn = new ODBCConnection(loginProperty);
```

What is missing in the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a raw string assignment (so no \ magic):

```
connectionString = @"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}; Server=MSS2008-term\SQLServer; Database=db; user ID=sa; Password=ABC.123";
```

Some others have problems, see [ODBC connection to external data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20346179/4509).

Maybe you can create the DSN by code, see [What is the simplest, most maintainable way to create a SQL Server ODBC Data Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170466/what-is-the-simplest-most-maintainable-way-to-create-a-sql-server-odbc-data-sou)

Comment: Okay, maybe you cannot use a connection string in that version of AX. Then use DSN.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have `Server` and `Database` in your connection string where I use `Data Source` and `Initial Catalog` for some reason.  You can do it like this, just changing/adding relevant parameters:

```js
public str getConnectionString() {
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder dbConnectionStringBuilder;

  dbConnectionStringBuilder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

  dbConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item('Data Source', 'YourServer');
  dbConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item('Initial Catalog', 'YourDatabase');
  dbConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item('Integrated Security', true);

  return dbConnectionStringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: No. I have tried it like this. But it get the same error.